# Как получить значение флага из формы Windows?

Tags: c#, реестр, control-panel

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста..Есть флаг в  Windows 7-> настройки системы->Удаленный доступ-> флаг Удаленный помощник,как вообще обратиться к этому флагу? 
Я хочу его включать при запуске программы, если он выключен
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`

Включение:

```
AllowTSConnections 1
fDenyTSConnections 0 
fAllowToGetHelp 1
```

Отключение:

```
AllowTSConnections 0
fDenyTSConnections 1
fAllowToGetHelp 0
```

http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1213/

Comment: фуф нашел, ваш ответ не совсем правильный, но направил меня в правильно русло....Спасибо.
В Windows 7 достаточно изменять ключ fAllowToGetHelp, но он теперь в другой папке HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance.

Comment: Вот и хорошо, друг друга просветили :)

Comment: Но появилась еще одна проблема.
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key=Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Remote Assistance");
key.SetValue("fAllowToGetHelp",1,RegistryValueKind.DWord);
UnauthorizedAccessException,я понимаю что нету доступа для записи, видимо нужно под админом, как это сделать в коде?

Comment: @markgenuine См. опцию манифеста `'requireAdministrator'`.

Comment: ок спасибо, буду курить!;)